Отсутствует /dev/mapper/устройство при переносе виртуалки с virtualbox на hyper-v
Есть необходимость перенести виртуальные машины с одной машины, где стоит virtualbox на другую машину с hyper-v. Было найдено решение конвертирования конвертирование виртуалки с VDI на VHD. При конвертировании ошибок не было. Создал виртуалку на hyper-v добавил конвертированную виртуалку формата VHD. При старте ловлю ошибку alert /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist dropping и далее initframs. Есть какие-либо способы решения?
